# WP7 Missing Design View in Blend 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, blend

I've installed WP7 Developer Tools but when I open blend I only get a XAML view.  No buttons for split view, both settings under View > Active or View > Split are both disabled?  Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Is your project in VB? If so, the problem is that Blend doesn't support VB projects yet. :s

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the [Blend 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) is installed.

Some features are not available in Blend 4 without the Blend 3 SDK.

Comment: I've got that.  Here's all of the Blend stuff installed:

Comment: Blend 3 SDK, Blend 4, Blend 4 Add-in Ffor Adobe FXG Import, Blend SDK for .NET 4, Blend SDK for Silverlight 4, Blend SDK For Window Phone 7

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should've closed this out a long time ago.  That is correct, Blend does not support WP7 VB projects.  However, the beta mango builds do.